# Chrome Extension - edit a text field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write my first Chrome extension. It would, when clicked, automatically fill the fields of an ID and password for my University's login page (which has its form's auto-fill disabled).
It's a very specific page.

I have a few problem.
I've searched Google and SO but couldn't find an explanation on how to change the value of a text field through Chrome. I know how to do this in HTML and JavaScript, however I couldn't get the proper input to modify its text.

I've also tried using jQuery using a few examples I've found, but no luck.
I have an HTML page (popup.html) which calls a JavaScript file.
I've also tried placing the JS in a content script

Here's the manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "tabs", "http://*/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js","content.js"]
      }
  ]
}
```

One of my attempt of popup.js (which gets called from popup.html) is:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    console.log(document)
});
```

I've also tried placing this code inside the content.js. same result,
It prints to console, however it prints the popup.html content..

I've also tried directly (and from the above method) to access an element directly by `document.getElementById()` but still no luck..

So,
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: would it be easier to simply force autofill on?

Comment: I don't know. :) When I look at the source, it says in the form autocomplete="OFF" can it be changed so it would allow autocomplete and remember what I entered? I dunno. also, I'd like to know how to do this anyway.

Comment: chances are your extension could just search for forms with autofill disabled and enable them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to inject a JavaScript file to the page using the "web_accessible_resources" attribute.  See here:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "tabs", "http://*/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js","content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
      }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["inject.js"]
}
```

**inject.js**

```
(function () {
    console.log('test');
}());
```

**content.js**

```
(function (chrome) {
    var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.type = 'text/javascript';
    js.src = chrome.extension.getURL('inject.js');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(chrome));
```

Then just put the JavaScript code you want to use in inject.js to manipulate the page.  Be sure to change matches to only match your University's login page.

The reason this is the case is because Chrome extensions can run and operate on their own regardless of which website you're on.  And they can continue to process as you switch pages.  They're in their own sandboxed environment.

Comment: It still doesn't work. it does the same thing. where should I put a call to inject.js? only in the manifest?

Comment: Yah. Works fine for the extension I made. It's important though that you change "matches" to be the actual page you want to manipulate.

Comment: PS - If you want to use JQuery, you'll have to load that library in "web_accessible_resources" as well.  Oh! and don't forget to reload the extension.  Personally, I forget to do that all the time and end up chasing bugs that I actually fixed the first time around. ;-)

Comment: Did both, but still no go. I'm trying just to log something to console, to see that the inject.js is getting called, but nothing is printed to console.. (Extension's console)

Comment: What's in your inject file?  You may have to wrap the statement in an executed function, i.e.: (function () { console.log('test'); }());

Comment: Also, I have a "run_at" attribute under "content_scripts" in my manifest file that may make a difference.  I'm updating my answer as such.

Comment: The code runs (without the function declaration. just the console.log) but when I do console.log(document) it still logs the popup.html

Comment: Oops. it doesn't run. there was a specific call to it inside the popup.html. when only declared in the manifest, nothing gets printed.

Comment: Oh crap. I just reread my code and realized I had to manually inject it.  Time to update my answer again.

Comment: Well, the code now runs, but if I log the document it still shows popup.html.

Comment: Are you logging the document from inject.js?

Comment: Yes. (function () {
    console.log(document);
}());

Comment: Get rid of this in your manifest.json file: "default_popup": "popup.html"

Comment: At least it tries now on the correct page, but I'm getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined in the contents.js

Comment: If that's the case, then your `console.log` must be in content.js.  I'm sure if we were in the same room I could identify the issue, but the above works fine for me and I've unfortunately run out of time. Perhaps another 'Stack Overflower' could provide insight.

Comment: nope. content.js contatins only the (function (chrome) { thing.
But I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem is the "run_at": "document_start".  At document_start on some pages/browsers it seems that the head is undefined.  Change that to "document_end" and then head is defined and it should work.  (That fixed it in my test)

Comment: @The Poet the asterisks are wildcard characters.  That attribute should be change to be more specific so that the script doesn't run against every resource (the second asterisk) on every domain (the first asterisk.)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use a simple content script that is executed on the login page. You don't even need any browser action or popup for that.

Here's a manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Fill my password",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Fills my password on University login page",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://www.myuniversity.edu/login.html"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's a content script:

```
// define your username and password
var myUsername = '...';
var myPassword = '...';

// find the fiends in your login form
var loginField = document.getElementById('...');
var passwordField = document.getElementById('...');

// fill in your username and password
loginField.value = myUsername;
passwordField.value = myPassword;

// if you want, you can even automaticaly submit the login form
var loginForm = document.getElementById('...');
loginForm.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround(chrome extension): [Autocomplete = on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh), but it could not work with some forms.